# Is "select * from funcA()" impossible in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, table-functions

After defining a table-valued function in [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), `select * from funcA()` is possible.

But in MySQL it seems impossible. Is that correct?

How can I do it in MySQL?
If this is not possible with a function, is there a similar way?
I want to split a string and bring it into a table to create the data I want.

Comment: I don't believe MySql functions can return a "TABLE" - only a set type of values (eg. string, numeric).  Depending on your MySql version, you could perhaps look at returning a JSON data structure from your function, and wrap that in MySql's built-in "JSON_TABLE" function (which will parse the Json and return a tabular set of data).  That may do the trick for you?